# header expires on PHP file with JS output

Tags: php, .htaccess, header, expires-header

How to put an expires header on a PHP file which outout a JS file?

## .htaccess

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/gif A29030400
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A29030400
ExpiresByType image/png A29030400
ExpiresByType text/css A29030400
ExpiresByType application/javascript A29030400
```

## header on JS file

```
Cache-Control   max-age=29030400
Connection  Keep-Alive
Date    Thu, 18 Oct 2012 09:23:16 GMT
Etag    "300000002c8ba-15f-4cc3069c72d00"
Expires Thu, 19 Sep 2013 09:23:16 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=94
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.4.3
```

## header on PHP file which outputs a JS file

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  1195
Content-Type    application/javascript
Date    Thu, 18 Oct 2012 09:23:16 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.4.3
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.3
```

## code PHP file

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
$js_output = array('something' => 'some value');
?>
var <?=json_encode($js_output)?>
```

Comment: you want the PHP file to create headers similar to the ones for the JS file delivered by apache?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Cache headers:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
header("Cache-Control: max-age=29030400");
header("Cache-Control: public", false); 
$js_output = array('something' => 'some value');
?>
var <?=json_encode($js_output)?>
```

see also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: isn't it possible to control from htaccess and apache?

Comment: Although this answer ads proper expires the server will always process the entire php and the end result is the server continuously returning response status of `200 OK`. The end result is nothing is ever fetched from client's cache.

Comment: You can't do this entirely in htaccess because of the php processor getting in the way. You might if you play around with `AddHandler` the `T flag` of mod_rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t and your expires headers but I think it will just end up showing the source code of the php. You would have to RemoveHandler on php extension and do your own and that is not optimal imho.

Comment: Not entirely true, @AnthonyHatzopoulos.  Most clients will cache the response and not ask for another copy until either (a) the end of the session or (b) the max-age runs out.  But when clients do make a conditional request, then this code will always return a new copy.  Client caching behavior varies wildly.

Comment: You must be either hitting reload, or going to the URL bar and hitting enter (which most browsers take as an implicit reload).  You get very different behavior, at least in Chrome, if you (1) open a new tab/window (2) turn on your debugging tools and select Network then (3) paste your URL into the address bar and hit enter.  In this case, which is more like casual browsing, you definitely get the page pulled from cache.  You are correct, however, that in cases where the browser decides to "reload" the page, a conditional get is more efficient.  It is just harder for a most people to code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep pretty much same Expire setting in your .htaccess i.e.:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/gif A29030400
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A29030400
ExpiresByType image/png A29030400
ExpiresByType text/css A29030400
ExpiresByType application/javascript A29030400
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
```

Then in your PHP code which is writing JS file use correct `Content-Type` and :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
exitIfNotModifiedSince(setLastModified());

function setLastModified($lastModified=NULL) {
    $pageModified = getlastmod();

    if(empty($lastModified) || ($lastModified < $pageModified))
        $lastModified = $pageModified;
    $headerModified = filemtime(__FILE__);
    if($headerModified > $lastModified)
        $lastModified = $headerModified;
    header('Last-Modified: ' . date("r",$lastModified));
    return $lastModified;
}

function exitIfNotModifiedSince($lastModified) {
    if(array_key_exists("HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE",$_SERVER)) {
        $ifModifiedSince = strtotime(preg_replace('/;.*$/', '',
                                     $_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]));
        if($ifModifiedSince >= $lastModified) { 
            header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
$jsData  = array('foo' => 'bar');
?>
var <?=json_encode( $jsData );?>
```

at the top. Monitor your headers in Firebug and it should show you something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control:max-age=29030400
Connection:close
Date:Wed, 24 Oct 2012 19:10:43 GMT
Expires:Wed, 25 Sep 2013 19:10:43 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8h DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Comment: Yes pretty much but then you also stated in your question `Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT` which is not the same as what I got via my attempts to get it right.

Comment: Same thing here, although this answer ads proper expires, the server will always process the entire php and the end result is the server continuously returning response status of `200 OK`. The end result is nothing is ever fetched from client's cache.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos: Please check my edited answer now which is utilizing `Last-Modified` and `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` headers.

Comment: @anubhava did you not see my post I made hours before that used `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE`?

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos: OMG, I had this tab opened since morning and didn't notice your answer was also posted here, I just looked at your comment here and reworked my answer based on that :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution will return a proper 304 response and halt the php execution allowing the client to use the cached copy. You can't do this entirely in htaccess using mod_rewrite as the php processor will always get in the way.

### .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType application/javascript   "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
```

### example.js.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

if (false === ($timestamp = getlastmod())) {
    if (false === ($timestamp = @filemtime(__FILE__))) {
        if (false === ($timestamp = @filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))) {
            trigger_error('Failed to retrieve timestamp', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
$timestamp_string = gmdate('r', $timestamp);

// Check if the client has the same page cached
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]) &&
    ($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"] == $timestamp_string)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
    exit;
}

// Inform the user agent what is our last modification date
header("Last-Modified: ".$timestamp_string);

$js_output = array('something' => 'some value');
echo 'var json = '.json_encode($js_output).PHP_EOL;
exit;
?>
```

### First GET Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 16:20:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) PHP/5.3.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Last-Modified: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 16:16:34 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Expires: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 16:20:05 GMT
Content-Length: 39
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

### Second and subsequent GET Responses

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 16:21:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) PHP/5.3.3
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Expires: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 16:21:31 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work but it helped me in the right direction :)
this solution works.. if you put it in your answer I will flag it as solved `function cache_headers(){
 $gmt_mtime = gmdate('r', filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
 header('Last-Modified: '.$gmt_mtime);
 header('Cache-Control: public');
 
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == $gmt_mtime){
   header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
   exit();
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @clarkk it worked perfectly when I tested it. How else did I get those responses. The only thing different is your using `gmdate('r'` which is shorthand for what I put and setting `cache-control public` which you should not need unless you are explicitly setting cache-control somewhere else like in your htaccess. Could it be `__FILE__` doesn't work right on your server for some odd reason.

Comment: There is another problem.. Now is seems like I can't use js versions of the file (eg file.js?v=43) unless the date the file is modified is changed?

Comment: @clarkk Well that's new, and not part of your original question  either. Secondly why would you want to serve the same file if it has not changed? The solution to your problem is pretty easy. There's a number of ways to solve it.

Comment: @clarkk I just tested my solution and it works fine with adding querystrings for cache busting. Open your Net panel and watch the responses.